# Find $\lim_{x \to 0}(e^x-1)(\frac{1}{x} - \left \lfloor{{\frac{1}{x}}}\right \rfloor)$

Tags: calculus

Find $\lim_{x \to 0}(e^x-1)(\frac{1}{x} - \left \lfloor{{\frac{1}{x}}}\right \rfloor)$
I was thinking about using the Sandwich Theorem and doing something like this: $$(e^x-1) < (e^x-1)(\frac{1}{x} - \left \lfloor{{\frac{1}{x}}}\right \rfloor) < (e^x-1)\cdot \frac{1}{x}$$
(this seems true because $x \to 0$)
and then I can say that the limit of the left side is $0$ and the limit of the right side is $0$ (because I get $=0$ both when $x \to 0^+$ and when $x \to 0^-$)...
So I get  the the limit of the original expression equals $0$. But I think this is not correct... Can someone tell me what is a correct way to solve it using the Sandwich Theorem (or something even simpler, **without using L'hospital's rule**)?

Comment: $0\leq\frac{1}{x} - \left \lfloor{{\frac{1}{x}}}\right \rfloor<1$

Comment: Limit of right hand side of inequaity is $1$ by L'hospital's rule.

Comment: And the inequality i.e. the left side is wrong. Check for $x=\frac{1}{100000}$.

Comment: @Aniket and Guest - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $0\leq z-\lfloor z\rfloor <1 $ so that

$\vert (e^x-1)(\frac{1}{x} - \left \lfloor{{\frac{1}{x}}}\right \rfloor)\vert \leq e^x-1\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0}(e^x-1)(\frac{1}{x} - \left \lfloor{{\frac{1}{x}}}\right \rfloor)=0$

Comment: I think that in order for your inequality to be true for all $x$, you need to add an absolute value. Also the limit will be $0$, not $1$.

Comment: @Guest Yes. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain how $z-\lfloor z\rfloor$ can be equal to $1$ ?

Comment: @Natalia Actually the inequality should have been $0 \le z-\lfloor z \rfloor < 1$.

Comment: it is never equal to 1 but that does not matter. < implies $\leq $ but  I will change it anyway. Thanks

Comment: Your answer helped a lot @Chilango , thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!